# SSMS SQL editor tool bar grayed out

Tags: sql, editor, ssms

I posted this earlier and obviously the person who marked it as duplicate did not read the post because the answer told me to do exactly what I said I was doing that does not work.

New install of SQL Server 2017 Express with existing databases. Login as sa or as a database owner. When you right click a table - Edit top 200 rows - open the SQL panel. The entire SQL editor toolbar is grayed out. I can copy the same SQL expression into a new query and the bar is active. I can execute the expression with Ctrl R when the bar is grayed out.

I have looked at dozens of posts but have not found the solution.

FYI Yes, I can write the SQL statement to update the table but it is faster, easier and safer to update it directly when you only have to change one number in a single row/column and I can update the data even with the tool bar grayed out.

Thank you to the one who has the solution.

Comment: Have you tried running Management Studio as an Administrator?

Comment: NO I had not but the tool bar is still grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Tried many different things.  Toolbar remained greyed out. Then looked at the shortcut for Execute by hovering over it and saw it was Alt X, ran the query using Alt X, the toolbar then became active, have no idea why.  Note:  Now the toolbar is active, the shortcut to Execute the query is now F5. (Alt X also still works).